# Oracle creating composite primary key with constants

Tags: oracle, composite-primary-key

Using oracle, how can I create a composite PRIMARY key with a constraint check.

Below is a sample of what would like to accomplish

```
create table T ( 
  n int,
dt DATE,
constraint t_pk primary key (n,
(dt=trunc(dt, 'dd')));
```

Comment: You only want to allow dates with time set to midnight? Or you want to allow any time, but only one per day?

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to allow dates with times set to midnight then use a separate check constraint:

```
create table T ( 
  n int,
  dt DATE,
  constraint t_chk check (dt=trunc(dt, 'dd')),
  constraint t_pk primary key (n, dt)
);
```

If you want to allow non-midnight times but only one per day then you can use a virtual column, as @gsalem also suggested:

```
create table T ( 
  n int,
  dt DATE,
  dd DATE generated always as (trunc(dt)),
  constraint t_pk primary key (n, dd)
 );
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=a217bddae2317198dd5f6b371533c868) showing both; notice the different times in the output of the two select statements.

Comment: Thanks, perfect. I want the first scenario

Comment: @AlexPoole have another coffee ;)

Answer (score 1):

Not withstanding the correctness of your stated requirement, you can do it by using virtual columns :

```
    create table T ( 
  n int,
dt DATE check (dt=trunc(dt,'dd')),
dt1 generated always as (trunc(dt,'dd')),
constraint t_pk primary key (n,
dt1));
```

Comment: dt1 is not needee. It will be same as dt always.